# QList<QString> not being used as model by QML ListView

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a `Q_PROPERTY` of type `QList<QString>` in a `c++` class that is not being shown in QML. The class looks like this:

```
class FooView : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT;
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QString> myStrings READ myStrings NOTIFY myStringsChanged);

private:
    QList<QString> m_strings;

public:
    FooView(QQuickItem * parent) : QQuickItem(parent), m_strings() {
        m_strings << "String one" << "String two";
    }

    QList<QString> myStrings() const {
        return m_strings;
    }

signals:
    void myStringsChanged();
};
```

The above class is registered as a QML type using `qmlRegisterType`. I try to use the property as a model to a `ListView` like so:

```
FooView {
    id: 'foo'
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: foo.myStrings
        delegate: Text {
            text: "Hi" // to be replaced with foo.myStrings[index]
        }
    }
}
```

Can you not use `QList<QString>`'s as models? I thought you could since it was listed as a simple list type.

Comment: `m_strings()`?  in the constructor.

Comment: `m_string()` override your `m_strings << "String one" << "String two";` so your are using empty list

Comment: @Phiber `m_strings << "String one" << "String two";` it runs after `m_string()`, although `m_string()` is unnecessary because a list is empty by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `QStringList` instead of `QList<QString>`:

```
class FooView : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList myStrings READ myStrings NOTIFY myStringsChanged)
    QStringList m_strings;
public:
    FooView(QQuickItem * parent=nullptr) :
        QQuickItem(parent)
    {
        m_strings << "String one" << "String two";
    }
    QStringList myStrings() const {
        return m_strings;
    }
signals:
    void myStringsChanged();
};
```

And going to the problem, you must use `modelData` when the model is a list as indicated by the [docs](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#models):

> Models that do not have named roles (such as the ListModel shown
>   below) will have the data provided via the modelData role. The
>   modelData role is also provided for models that have only one role. In
>   this case the modelData role contains the same data as the named role.

---

```
FooView {
    id: foo
    anchors.fill: parent
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: foo.myStrings
        delegate: Text {
            text: modelData
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the no qstringlistmodel comaptibility with qml?

Comment: @Mike QStringList and QStringListModel are both supported.